# When mirroring ingress traffic on an interface with tc, are only the packets destined for the interface mirrored?

Tags: networking, tc

I have a Linux box with 3 physical interfaces, one for management (has an IP address) and two for receiving mirrored traffic from two separate switches that make up a link aggregation group (LAG). The LAG policy is per packet, which means packets making up a flow could be seen on different interfaces.

I'm trying to configure the mirroring of both of these interfaces to a single dummy interface with `tc` so I can see all the packets on the same interface. However, when I do so, all I see on the dummy interface is broadcast traffic (ie. LLDP, ARP, DHCP). So I'm wondering if `tc` is only mirroring packets actually destined for the physical interface to the dummy interface that's the destination for the mirror?

Here's my setup:

```
ip link add dummy0 type dummy
ip link set dummy0 up
tc qdisc add dev enp6s19 ingress
tc qdisc add dev enp6s20 ingress
tc filter add dev enp6s19 parent ffff: \
  protocol all u32 match u8 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev dummy0
tc filter add dev enp6s20 parent ffff: \
  protocol all u32 match u8 0 0 action mirred egress mirror dev dummy0
```

Comment: I'm open to other suggestions as well! Can you maybe give a little more context to your suggestion? Thx!

Comment: Will a bond or team interface work in this case if the other end of the links are just mirroring ports (as opposed to ports configured for bonding/teaming/link aggregation)?